# S3 method for class vector in R

Tags: r, oop

Is it possible to create an S3 method for all vector types at once? I.e. one that is called for a numeric, integer, character etc. vector. Something like this:

```
first_element <- function(x, ...){
  UseMethod("first_element", x)
}

first_element.vector <- function(x){
  x[1]
}

first_element(1:3)
```

Comment: How is this different than `[`?

Comment: I don't believe so. There is no class `vector`, see the description of classes in `?class`.

Comment: @Benjamin: That's just an example, it's not supposed to be a useful function.

Comment: It might be useful to describe a more practical use case. While I don't think this is strictly possible as a method, you may consider using `is.atomic` to terminate a function with an error if the vector isn't an atomic type

Comment: You can use the fall through to  "first_element.default" and define that function to handle any vector, or report an error.

Answer (score 1):

By type, I assume you mean `class`. The `structure` function will allow you to define multiple classes of a vector.

First, create some data and look at its class.

```
set.seed(1)
vector <- rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 3)

class(vector)
>[1] "numeric"

head(vector)    
>[1] -0.8793614  1.5509300 -1.5068858  5.7858424  1.9885233 -1.4614052
```

Now use the `structure` function on your vector to define additional classes. Then check the `class` again and call `str` function to see the classes and data of the `new_vector` object.

```
new_vector <- structure(vector, class = c("character", "integer", "numeric", "double"))

class(new_vector)
>[1] "character" "integer"   "numeric"   "double"

str(new_vector)  
>Classes 'character', 'integer', 'numeric', 'double'  num [1:100] -0.879 1.551 -1.507 5.786 1.989 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this interesting workaround. However I was hoping for a solution that doesn't require changing the vector object.

Comment: If you don't want to change the vector object, just run the 'structure' function without assigning it to a new variable. You can wrap that in an additional function to print the desired elements. Can you please give us some more information about what you are trying to accomplish? Thanks

Comment: Frankly, I was just playing around with the S3 concept and for that I used the simplest idea for methods I could come up with, which was just returning the first element of an object. So I ran into the problem that I needed different methods for lists, data.frames and identical methods for all vector classes (numeric, integer, character, ...), which seemed to me a lot of unnecessary repetition of code and I was wondering if there is a better way in case I will run into the same problem for a more useful method. In hindsight there may not be many real life applications of that.

Comment: If I have to change the class of the object, it's probably easier to write different functions and decide manually which one to use for which class. But maybe my whole question wasn't as sensible as I thought to begin with ;)